# How to force table width to equal to its child td width and allow table to extend beyond viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table with dynamic row + column.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>column 1</td>
    <td>column 2</td>
    <td>column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>13</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to have the td width to always equal to its content. At the moment, the table width expands according to the td width. However, the total table width is constrained by the page width once the number of column increases.

I'm trying to find a way to maintain the auto td width but allow the table to expand beyond the page width. I attached a simple drawing of what I meant below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this style:

```
table {
  white-space: nowrap;  //prevent wrapping
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3pj2vsdb/1)